XSL for each text starts-with select in variable
i have this XML in input:
 <root> RH03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951171                                                                                      
 610000001                  93001                  G0305101700000000004575EUR270524C000000000000,00IT44                 
 620000001001270524270524D000000000649,3450TE                ITDA00DPN145                                               
 630000001001HAYS SRL/AVIS BUDGET ITALIA S.P.A./AR885265/2355070853/B2B/RCUR/OE5OA5200P4907R3                           
 640000001EUR270524C000000000000,00                                                                                     
 EF03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951171           0000001                              0000006                               
 RH03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951349                                                                                      
 610000001                  93001                  Z0305101699000078389249USD270524C000000001320,97IT72                 
 640000001USD270524C000000001320,97                                                                                     
 EF03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951349           0000001                              0000004                               
</root>

i want iterate for each string starts with " RH" for parse whole multiline string. for example in my xml input i have 2 strings that starts with RH:

RH03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951171  ....
RH03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951349  ....

my xslt is this:
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                xmlns:ns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.03"
                xmlns:BODY="urn:CBI:xsd:CBIBdyBkToCstmrStmtReq.00.01.02"
                xmlns:LMSG="urn:CBI:xsd:CBIBkToCstmrStmtReqLogMsg.00.01.02"
                xmlns:HE2E="urn:CBI:xsd:CBIHdrSrv.001.07"
                xmlns:HTRT="urn:CBI:xsd:CBIHdrTrt.001.07"
                xmlns:IDST="urn:CBI:xsd:CBIIdyStmtReqLogMsg.00.01.02"
                xmlns:DLST="urn:CBI:xsd:CBIDlyStmtReqLogMsg.00.01.02"
                xmlns:PRST="urn:CBI:xsd:CBIPrdcStmtReqLogMsg.00.01.02"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
                xmlns:myns="py_ns"
                extension-element-prefixes="exsl myns"
                exclude-result-prefixes="exsl ns">


    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" indent="yes" method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
                
        <xsl:for-each select="//text[starts-with(., ' RH')]">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

but when i do:
<xsl:for-each select="//text[starts-with(., ' RH')]">
<xsl:value-of select="." />

i dont view nothing.
is correct my code?
i must use lxml library and i use :
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
and
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
i want:
RH03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951171 610000001 93001 G030510170 ......................... 0000001
and this:
RH03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951349 610000001 93001 ......................................... EF03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951349 0000004
same tips?
thanks
regards

What is the exact result you want to get? Your stylesheet declares  method="xml" but does not create any XML markup. Do you need the strings to be numbered?

Using the libsxlt processor (or any XSLT 1.0 processor that supports the EXSLT str:tokenize() extension function) you can do:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <strings>
        <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(normalize-space(root), ' ')[starts-with(., 'RH')]">
            <string>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </string>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </strings>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Added:
The result you want is still not clear. I am guessing (!) you want to do something like:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <strings>
        <xsl:for-each select="str:split(root, ' RH')">
            <string>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('RH', .)"/>
            </string>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </strings>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


thanks works but i want all multilinestring not only:
RH03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951171 i want until next " RH"

I am not sure understand this. There are no "multiline strings" in the input you posted here. It's just strings separated by sequences of the space character. Please edit your question and add the exact result (as code) you expect to get.

And also: Will the first string always start with " RH"?

i want:
RH03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951171
610000001                  93001                  G030510170 .........................          0000001
and this:
RH03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951349
610000001                  93001                  .........................................
EF03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951349           0000001

Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

I have edited my answer, but in the absence of clear requirements I am mostly guessing.

exaclty now is correct thanks!

The text is in a single text node that is a child of the root element; in XSLT 3 you could use e.g.
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(root, '\n')[starts-with(., ' RH')]" separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Output is e.g.
 RH03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951171                                                                                      
 RH03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951349  

XSLT 3 can be used with Python using the saxonche package.`

thanks but i must use lxml... I use also
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" and xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
